# Are The Young Turks Funded by George Soros?

Tags: united-states, politics

I was researching [The Young Turks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Turks)<sup>*1</sup> and [Wolf PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_PAC)<sup>*2</sup> (But specifically TYT) and found accusations of them being funded by George Soros on a few websites (such as [Soros in Vermont](http://watchdog.org/142762/soros-in-vermont/)).

I can't really find any direct evidence about them being funded by Soros, and it appears that TYT actually [did a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jK8gT_OQDfA) dispelling the notion.
However, the video was in 2012, and the accusations appear to be from 2014, although they were also present in 2012 apparently.
In TYT's video, they claim that Soros funds the media conglomerate that they are a part of, but that they send money to the conglomerate and do not receive any money from them (and added that they'd be glad to take anyone's money if they'll donate to them).

Additionally, when researching the articles talking about TYT being funded by Soros, I noticed that they didn't really provide me any direct evidence (such as financial documents) proving the statements. This seems like "That which can be proven without evidence can be dismissed without evidence", but I'm not sure, especially with the date mismatch between 2012 and 2014.

Did the situation change? Is TYT funded directly or indirectly by George Soros?

<sup>*1 An American political commentary web series</sup>
<sup>*2 An American political action committee</sup>

Comment: *the video was in 2012, and the accusations appear to be from 2014* The fact that someone has published a statement or even proof, does not stop all people wanting to accuse

Answer (score 8):

Soros in Vermont links to [The New American](http://www.thenewamerican.com/usnews/constitution/item/17402-socialists-and-soros-fight-for-article-v-convention) as source of the claim. They in turn name [Media Research Center](http://www.mrc.org/commentary/soros-funded-lefty-media-reach-more-300-million-every-month) as source. Their claim is:

> In fact, Soros funds nearly every major left-wing media source in the United States. Forty-five of those are financed through his support of the Media Consortium. That organization 'is a network of the country's leading, progressive, independent media outlets.' The list is predictable - everything from Alternet to the Young Turks.

They do not provide a source for this claim.

[CNSNews.com](http://www.cnsnews.com/blog/mike-ciandella/11-million-soros-money-tied-magazine-released-mcconnell-tape) has a more specific claim:

> Mother Jones is the news outlet of The Foundation for National Progress, the left-wing "umbrella organization that exists to publish and support Mother Jones." It also founded the Media Consortium. The FNP received $485,000 in Soros funding in 2008. The Media Consortium, also still under the umbrella of the FNP, has received $675,000 since 2000, adding up to $1,160,000. Those figures come from 990 forms from Soros' Open Society Foundations.

The reference to 990 forms is rather vague, and they do not link to any further sources. The claim is repeated by various right wing websites, but none cite any actual sources.

However, the website of the [Open Society Foundations](https://www.opensocietyfoundations.org/about/programs/us-programs/grantees/foundation-national-progress) does have a grant over $200,000 going to the Media Consortium.

But I could not find any source that states that the Media Consortium actually gave all or part of that money to The Young Turks. It doesn't seem like the consortium gives money to their members at all, but that instead the members give money to the [consortium](https://www.themediaconsortium.org/about/): "Participating members pay annual dues based on a sliding scale.".

**Summary**

There is no evidence that George Soros is funding The Young Turks.

George Soros is the chairman of an organization which donated money to a consortium of which TYT are a member, but from which they do not gain financial benefits.

I'm not sure how this might be seen as a scandal, and most of the sources seem at least vaguely antisemitic with their claims that a Jew is secretly controlling the media.

Comment: Looking at your sources, it is entirely plausible that the Young Turks do get indirect funding from George Soros.... possibly $35 to $38.25 USD per year, from the looks of it.